# What is the equivalent of Python's itertools.product in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

The Python code below generates all the different vectors of size `ndim`, built from the values `0` and `1`:

```
import itertools

ndim = 8
A = list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=ndim))
print (A)
```

Is it possible to do the same in Fortran? What is then the equivalent of `intertools.product` in Fortran?

Comment: What you are looking for, is called Cartesian Product. I don't think if there is such intrinsic concept in Fortran standard. But, given its definition, it should be easy to code it in Fortran. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/itertools-product

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do the same in Fortran, though some might think it a little more bothersome.  What is the equivalent of `itertools.product` ?  I haven't a scooby what `itertools.product` is in the first place.  But this little function seems to do what you want ...

```
  FUNCTION bit_vectors(ndim) RESULT(bv)
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: ndim
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(0:2**ndim-1,ndim) :: bv
    INTEGER :: jx
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(0:ndim-1) :: bits
    bits = [(jx,jx=0,ndim-1)]
    DO jx = 0, 2**ndim-1
       bv(jx,:) = MERGE(1,0,BTEST(jx,bits))
    END DO
  END FUNCTION bit_vectors
```

I imagine you could generalise this approach for a wider range of purposes.

Comment: Your code works perfectly !!! Thank you very much for your kindness !!! I appreciate...